# Set tick width when using axes_grid matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a shared y-axes plot (3 plots in a row).
The following approaches did not work when I tried to set the tick widths for all three subplots.

First I tried to set the tick width via rc params. This works for the tick lengths but not for the width. I get the following error message:

```
KeyError: 'xtick.major.width is not a valid rc parameter.See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'
```

When looking into the list xtick.major.width is a valid parameter so what else could be wrong?

Here the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import scipy.io
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Grid
import numpy as np
from pylab import *


# set tick width
mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 2

#ignore all the data import please
X = scipy.io.loadmat('Ud04.mat')
psi11_final=X['psi11_final']
psi12_final=X['psi12_final']
psi21_final=X['psi21_final']
psi22_final=X['psi22_final']
psi11_final=flipud(psi11_final)
psi12_final=flipud(psi12_final)
psi21_final=flipud(psi21_final)
psi22_final=flipud(psi22_final)

na11_final=X['na11_final']
na12_final=X['na12_final']
na21_final=X['na21_final']
na22_final=X['na22_final']
na11_final=flipud(na11_final)
na12_final=flipud(na12_final)
na21_final=flipud(na21_final)
na22_final=flipud(na22_final)

np11_final=X['np11_final']
np12_final=X['np12_final']
np21_final=X['np21_final']
np22_final=X['np22_final']
np11_final=flipud(np11_final)
np12_final=flipud(np12_final)
np21_final=flipud(np21_final)
np22_final=flipud(np22_final)

extot=na11_final+na12_final+na21_final+na22_final+np11_final+np12_final+np21_final+np22_final


k_bar=X['k_bar']
nkap_bar=X['nkap_bar']
nkap_bar=nkap_bar[0,0]
kapmin=k_bar[0,0]
kapmax=k_bar[0,nkap_bar-1]

mu_bar=X['mu_bar']
nmu_bar=X['nmu_bar']
nmu_bar=nmu_bar[0,0]
mumin=mu_bar[0,0]
mumax=mu_bar[0,nmu_bar-1]

fig = plt.figure(1, (12., 4.))
grid = Grid(fig, 111, # similar to subplot(111)
                nrows_ncols = (1,3), # creates 3x1 grid of axes
                axes_pad=0.1) # pad between axes in inch.

for i in range(3):
    #grid[i].imshow(extot,interpolation='nearest')
    grid[i].imshow(extot,aspect='auto',extent=(kapmin,kapmax,mumin,mumax),interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Then I tried to set the tick width by making the following change in the last lines of the code and getting rid of the rc parameter stuff at the beginning:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(axis='both',width=5)
for i in range(3):
    #grid[i].imshow(extot,interpolation='nearest')
    grid[i].imshow(extot,aspect='auto',extent=(kapmin,kapmax,mumin,mumax),interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

This only changed the tick thickness of the last plot in the 3*1 series. Is there a way to access all of them without using rc params? It would be also helpful to get rid of the appearing overlap of the tick labels. There I tried to set the ticks manually with

```
#plt.xticks([0.02,0.04,0.06], [0.02,0.04,0.06])
#plt.yticks([-0.3,-1.2,-1.1,-1.0], [-0.3,-1.2,-1.1,-1.0])
```

but again it only changed the appearence in the last of the 3 plots on the grid.

Comment: that call works for me, what version of mpl are you using?

Comment: and for me as well.. In general is would be neater to do this with rcParams rather than iterating over tick_params.

Comment: In [1]: import matplotlib as mpl

In [2]: print mpl.__version__
1.0.1 when I try to reinstall matplotlib it says that I already have the newest version, why in the last workaround i proposed only 1 of the subplots on the grid is affected?